# Failed to load PDF document on hybrid mobile app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am not able to view/download the pdf file on hybrid mobile app which has been implemented with phonegap,ionic and angularJS. Below is the code to generate the pdf and the same code is working on desktop web application and both code consuming same service.

```
$scope.generateReport = function(clientId){clientService.generateReport(clientId).then(
function(response){var file = new Blob([ response.data ], {
type : 'application/pdf'});
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL);});};
```

Comment: Any errors in console/logcat?

Comment: Nothing. Infact I wrote console.log statements before and after window.open().SO file  and fileURL values getting properly

Comment: is there any cordova plugin available for the same

Comment: Hi thepio,could you plz share solution if you have

Comment: Hi durgesg, is the `$scope.generateReport` a function you are calling upon clicking on a button or a link or something?

Comment: yes thepio, $scope.generteReport() has been implemented in AngularJs controller and will be called by clicking on button

Comment: Could you possibly generate the url when `$scope` is initialised or what ever need to happend before it's generated? Basically just set let's say `$scope.yourPDFurl` at some point and then you could use a more proofed way with the download link on mobile and use `<a ng-href="{{yourPDFurl}}" download="nameOfPDF.pdf">Download PDF</a>`. The download attribute would make the difference on mobile devices. You could style the link to look like a button.

Comment: No, that will be dynamically generated based on the record i clicked on.

Comment: instead of using window.open(fileURL);  persising  file as window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {var fileEntry = entry;   entry.createWriter(function(writer) {writer.onwrite = function(evt) {console.log("write success");};
writer.write( file );}, function(error) {console.log(error);});
}, function(error){console.log(error);});},function(event){ console.log( "failed" );}); However it is always executing console.log("failed");

Comment: You could also have the `<a>` link hidden somewhere with a suitable dynamic id/attribute based on the record and fake a click on it when pressing the initial button.

Comment: tried with your solution,even though getting same problem

Comment: Ok, then I don't know how you could achieve what you want. If you have your CSP and whitelists fine and no error logs. Sorry.

Comment: ok fine,then re-assign to some one who has good knowledge on this.Thanks thepio

Comment: Could you help?